# Javascript lazy enumerable

Tags: javascript, arrays, enumerable

Is there any way to convert regular array into **lazy enumerable**?

I want the code below produces only **one log**, not ten ones:

```
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];


items.map((i) => {
    console.log('expensive process');
    return i;
})
.findIndex((i) => true);
```

Comment: To answer your question more accurately, please describe your use cases...

Comment: i want doing something like this const goodChild = Array.from(parent.children).filter(calculateCondition).map(c => { child: c, area: calcArea(c) })[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to stop right after you find the right one element.

```js
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];


items.find((i) => {
    if(i){
        console.log('expensive process');
    }
    
    return i;
});
```

Comment: i can't do that, there are severals expensive .map & .filter before the last .find

Comment: @HeyyyMarco
You can't stop `.map`. You can use yeild to pause and resume a generator function. You can use async/await:

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const asyncRes = await Promise.all(arr.map(async (i) => {
 await sleep(10);
 return i + 1;
}));

console.log(asyncRes);
// 2,3,4